# Texture feature extraction using Gray Level Cooccurence Matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, glcm

I'm doing a project in liver tumor classification. I used [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22187-glcm-texture-features/content/GLCM_Features1.m) and it gave some output. I don't know whether I'm correct.

Actually I initially used Region Growing method for liver segmentation and from that I segmented tumor using FCM. So, to this GLCM program, I gave the tumor segmented image as input. Was I correct? If so, I think, then, my output will also be correct.

I gave the parameters exactly as in the example. Actually what do they mean? Do I need to change them for different images? If so, how to give the parameters? I'm completely new to this. So, kindly guide me.

I got this output. Am I correct?

```
stats =

    autoc: [1.857855266614132e+000 1.857955341199538e+000]
    contr: [5.103143332457753e-002 5.030548650257343e-002]
    corrm: [9.512661919561399e-001 9.519459060378332e-001]
    corrp: [9.512661919561385e-001 9.519459060378338e-001]
    cprom: [7.885631654779597e+001 7.905268525471267e+001]
    cshad: [1.219440700252286e+001 1.220659371449108e+001]
    dissi: [2.037387269065756e-002 1.935418927908687e-002]
    energ: [8.987753042491253e-001 8.988459843719526e-001]
    entro: [2.759187341212805e-001 2.743152140681436e-001]
    homom: [9.930016927881388e-001 9.935307908219834e-001]
    homop: [9.925660617240367e-001 9.930960070222014e-001]
    maxpr: [9.474275457490587e-001 9.474466930429607e-001]
    sosvh: [1.847174384255155e+000 1.846913030238459e+000]
    savgh: [2.332207337361002e+000 2.332108469591401e+000]
    svarh: [6.311174784234007e+000 6.314794324825067e+000]
    senth: [2.663144677055123e-001 2.653725436772341e-001]
    dvarh: [5.103143332457753e-002 5.030548650257344e-002]
    denth: [7.573115918713391e-002 7.073380266499811e-002]
    inf1h: [-8.199645492654247e-001 -8.265514568489666e-001]
    inf2h: [5.643539051044213e-001 5.661543271625117e-001]
    indnc: [9.980238521073823e-001 9.981394883569174e-001]
    idmnc: [9.993275086521848e-001 9.993404634013308e-001]
```

Kindly guide me. Thank you

Comment: Please give some more information regarding your project

Answer (score 0):

its ok but i don't think we usually  need all this extra information i usually prefer to use the following code

```
GLCM2 = graycomatrix(img,'Offset',[1 1]);
stats = graycoprops(GLCM2);
```

i hope it will help you